# How to create multidimensional array/object in a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Might be a bit of a simple question but I can't figure it out.

I try to create an object like this:

```
var labelTestData = [
    {label: "person a", times: [{"starting_time": 1355752800000, "ending_time": 1355759900000}, {"starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000}]},
    {label: "person b", times: [{"starting_time": 1355759910000, "ending_time": 1355761900000}, ]},
    {label: "person c", times: [{"starting_time": 1355761910000, "ending_time": 1355763910000}]}
  ];
```

I need to do this in a loop like this:

```
let test2Array = [];    
resp.results.forEach(function(r) {
    test2Array = [
    label: r.person,
    times:{
       "starting-time": new Date(r.birthdate).getTime(),
       "ending-time": new Date(((r.birthdatedt.addDays(119)).toISOString()).split('T')[0]) .getTime()
    }]
})
```

I am almost there but how can I add more "times" to a "person" so that the result will be like this:

```
 {label: "person a", times: [{"starting_time": 1355752800000, "ending_time": 1355759900000}, {"starting_time": 1355767900000, "ending_time": 1355774400000}]},
```

I try to do it with an if construction. So the first time I push person and the first time. The second (or more) time I want to add the additional times.

Comment: what is resp.results?

Comment: And the problem is? And what is `resp`? -> [mcve]

Comment: What can't you figure out? What is the resulting array supposed to look like?

Comment: It's `starting_time` not `starting-time`, `ending_time` not `ending-time`

Comment: You are very close, but but `test2Array` has the wrong syntax. In JavaScript arrays are simple lists, while objects are key value pairs. So `test2Array.push({ label: r.person, times: {...}});`

Comment: `test2Array = [ ... ]` - that's not how you add elements to an array.

Comment: Thank you as well Randy, this did solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code answer your question:

```
let test2Array = [];    
resp.results.forEach(function(r) {
    test2Array.push({
       label: r.person,
       times: [{
       "starting-time": new Date(r.birthdate).getTime(),
       "ending-time": new Date(((r.birthdatedt.addDays(119)).toISOString()).split('T')[0]) .getTime()
    }]})
})
```

The next time you want to add additional times to a person, you can do this:

```
const index = test2Array.findIndex(item => item.label == "the person you want to target")
test2Array[index].times.push({
       "starting-time": new Date(r.birthdate).getTime(),
       "ending-time": new Date(((r.birthdatedt.addDays(119)).toISOString()).split('T')[0]) .getTime()
    })
```

Comment: I changed my initial question a bit because it got a little bit more complicated, for me.

Comment: how do you decide which one has additional times?

Comment: I use a groupby and within this groupby I loop do the loop. So If person one has only one time, it loops once. If person three has 5 times, it loops, obviously, five times 

resp.groupBy("person").forEach(function(lf) { 
          
          lf.results.forEach(function(r) {

Comment: i've also updated my answer. Is it what you asking for?